# Failed to start application on webpshere during redeploy or installation

Tags: java, websphere

I have problem with deploying application on webpshere using thinclient.sh Sometimes (not regularly) I got exception during redeploy or installation application. There are `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` with a lot of java classes for example:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

or there is problem with opening libraries:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
Failed to open archive [ WEB-INF/lib/ifxjdbc-3.5.jar ]
```

or some NPE:

```
[1/30/14 12:09:13:203 CET] 00000072 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl populateJavaNameSpace SRVE8084E: An unexpected internal server error occurred while populating the namespace.
                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebCollaboratorComponentMetaDataImpl.getJ2EEName(WebCollaboratorComponentMetaDataImpl.java:63)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl$1.getValue(ApplicationServerImpl.java:113)
```

These exception occurs randomly (For me). So these application are deployed to my server but they failed to start. **After restarting my server all application start with no problem** so I think my apps are OK. Problem is probably with my webpshere server. I have Base 8.5.5.0  vesion. Anyone know how to fix this issue

**UPDATE**

I install this application using `wsadminlib.py` which I download from here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/apps/download/index.jsp?contentid=166422&filename=wsadminlib.py.zip&method=http&locale= and call method installApplication

Comment: Can you post more details around exactly how you are deploying your application, meaning post the scripts you are running.

Comment: Is it your development server? Usually it happens then you try update/install applications without restart server. There is special configuration case for that. More details you can read in the documentation - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wbit.help.runtime.doc%2Fdeploy%2Ftopics%2Ftdevmode.html

Comment: Don't forget to try the WebSphere forum if you haven't yet: http://ibm.biz/websphere-forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found where was the problem.

This article helps me a lot: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftxml_callappinstall.html

I started application immediately after deploy. This was my bad. I should wait for a while